# re run git file comparison algorithm

Tags: git

I moved all my files into a folder ignored by git (an over-zealous `.gitignore`).  When I fixed the problem in `.gitignore` I had a set of deleted files and a set of new untracked files - even though most of the files are identical.  How do I ask git to re-run its comparison algorithm to properly track changes in these files?

*Summery of what I typed*:

```
mkdir ./libs
git mv ./src-code ./libs/src-code #I might just have used mv
#a few changes
git status 
# nothing changed, huh?
# oh, I am ignoring all libs directories in .gitignore, 
#   I meant to only ignore the one at the root - fixed
git status
#   deleted:    ./src-code/...
# Untracked files:
#       ./libs/src-code
```

Comment: Since the `git mv` worked, I have deleted my answer

Comment: @VonC Okay, many thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git mv` doesn't actually anything you can't do without it, because git doesn't *really* have a concept of "a move" at most levels.<sup>†</sup>  For the most part moves are represented in git as an added-file / deleted-file pair, which git may detect and *treat* as a move when displaying a diff or updating the working tree.  [From your question, it looks like you already know this, but just for completeness...]

One consequence of this is that it's totally fine to use normal non-git `mv` (or any other tool) to move git-controlled files around; the results won't be any different (and this can be handy if, for instance, you want to use some special tool to do the moves).

*However*, as with any change to your working tree, git doesn't really "know" about it until you've added the changed thing to the index with `git add`.

So `git mv A B` is just a convenience command roughly equivalent to `mv A B; git add -u A; git add B`; since you already had done the `mv`, you could have just used `git add` in the same way to tell git about the new and deleted files.  An easier way, if it's ok for other changes in your working-tree to be put into the index, would just be `git add -A`, which adds both new files and changes in the working-tree (including deleted files) to the index.

[That's usually what I do: `mv A B;` *...more changes...*; `git add -A; git commit`...]

────────
<sup>†</sup>  *This is different than many other source-control systems, which may have an explicit notion of moves that's stored in commits, etc.*

Comment: Okay, I just tried this out and its true.  I was too chicken to do the add when I was unsure whether it would track the changes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem, it's because I've `mv`ed instead of `git mv`ed. Try just `mv`ing them back, then `git mv`ing them where you want them.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think to do this, but it works nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`git mv` is a rather excessive solution. Simply `git add libs/src-code` and then `git commit -a`. git will detect the rename.

That said, it's usually nicer for humans if you make the rename its own commit.

Comment: This was @VonC's answer (now deleted):  when I did this it considered the files to be new rather than track the changes between the files.  My guess is that this is because the detected delete (when I moved the files) occurred a long time before the detected new file (when I modified .gitignore) - causing git to think that is unlikely

Comment: It may have been those few changes in step 3 that caused it to not match them up. I don't think the modification times on the file have anything to do with it.